# Implement Producer-Consumer Pattern Using Executor Framework

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads, a consumer and a producer. The consumer thread is the main thread while the producer thread is created by a third party library I use.

You make a request for a `List` of data to the producer thread using `ProducerChannel`'s `requestData()`, which returns immediately. Then, the producer thread will generate data one by one asynchronously and uses a call back method to send each of them. I want the method that requests data to return the result synchronously. The most straightforward way would be to use `wait()` and `notify()` like below.

```
public class DataFeed {
    boolean done;
    private List<Data> dataList;
    private ProducerChannel producerChannel;

    // This method should be synchronous.
    public List<Data> getDataList() {
        this.producerChannel.requestData();

        while (!done) {
            wait();
        }

        List<Data> dataList = this.dataList;
        this.dataList = null;

        return dataList;
    }

    // This is the call back method invoked by the producer thread.  
    public void generated(Data data) {
        if (data == null) {
            done = true; // End of data.
            notify();
        }
        else {
            this.dataList.add(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there's only one consumer thread in the entire application. That's why `DataFeed` has only one `List` to hold the result for each request. I learned that the Executor framework is now the preferred way to manage threads. How can I refactor this class so that it does not use `Thread` objects explicitly while not creating additional threads?

Comment: I think this post is very confusing and the "correct" answer is from the OP and not very helpful. I don't recommend this post for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the OP. While BlockingQueue would certainly work, I learned that Semaphore would be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take a look at the producer-consumer example on the BlockingQueue javadoc:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't really follow you. This class doesn't create any thread. So using the executor framework won't hep you here.

Instead os using explicit synchronization and thread communication using wait and notify, you could just use a BlockingQueue. The producer adds the list to the blocking queue when data is ready, and the consuler blocks while the blocking queue is empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the size of the resulting collection or getting items by index, then BlockingQueue might be what you need.  If you DO care about those things (i.e. you actually need a `java.util.List`, instead of `Collection`, or if you're not ok using a delayed collection for some reason) then you can still use `wait()` and `notify()`.

You'll need to add they synchronized keyword to your getDataList and generated methods, otherwise you'll get an `IllegalStateMonitorException`.

Like this: `public synchronized List<Data> getDataList() throws InterruptedException{`

But if that's the route that you want to go, use caution.  Any number of threads would be able to call `getDataList()` at the same time.  Even though it's synchronized, you're releasing the monitor lock by calling `wait()`

Personally, I'd go with the BlockingQueue

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the example](http://java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/ProducerandconsumerbasedonBlockingQueue.htm) on how to use Blocking Queue to tackle producer consumer problems